# Netbeans installation throw error

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, netbeans

I get this persistent error while attempting to install NetBeans using the installer `netbeans-8.2-javase-linux.sh"

[image: error screen shot]

I have checked the log message the only complain I noticed is:

```
java.io.IOException: error=13, Permission denied [2018-03-14 07:30:58.791]:
```

Some about permissions of which I am running the installer with administrative privilege.

Can anyone help?

Comment: @AkhilVarma After observing the log, I had to.

Comment: Try this `chmod 755 /path/of/file/netbeans-8.2-javase-linux.sh` then execute it.

Comment: @AkhilVarma It already had such permission. Anyway, I tried again still same error.

Comment: Can you paste the output of `ls -l /path/of/file/netbeans-8.2-javase-linux.sh` here below

Comment: @AkhilVarma here you go `-rwxr-xr-x 1 tobi tobi 98264064 Nov  9 12:46 Netbeans/netbeans-8.2-javase-linux.sh`

Comment: Other than that, Refer this Link  https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/e_QvcAkfU8k

Comment: @AkhilVarma The link actually helped, I had to double check again permission of JVM this unexpected because i have been running other programs with Java, i realized all subfiles, programs, and directory in my installation directory belong to group root..... anyways I change group to "me", problem fixed. **Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

- Issue is related to permissions **[follow comments above]**
  **Refer the Link Below, It May Help**
  [Click here](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/google-web-toolkit/e_QvcAkfU8k)